# Forever lost in if, while and foreach statement - cannot get the appropriate condition to run

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, while-loop, boolean

I have spent a fair few hours on this problem, it's quite basic but has gotten out of hand quickly.

Because it is rather confusing I'll post what I want it to do and what it actually does

**Goal**

If a supervisor is busy, it will move onto the next one, if they are all busy it will display a message "Sorry all supervisors are busy". Likewise with all employees.

**Method**

I want the method to read all the supervisors, if one is not busy it continues down, then I want it to read all of the employees, if one is not busy it continues down.

Then it reads if the employee has the appropriate skill and if the success has already been met, to avoid the same person being assigned the same job.

if this is all good so far, it checks if the supervisor is occupied, if it is, it reverts back and changes supervisor.

It then assigns the employee with the information, also assigning the supervisor with some and checking the 'success' condition.

From here it starts to get a bit sloppy, as you can see, I have put numerous boolean statements to simply get the program out of the loops and exit it.

After all of this, the program assigns the work, so far, it works to a reasonable degree, but I want there to be a message that states that if all of the supervisors are busy that no more work can be allocated.

I have in the past, used `MessageBox.Show` after foreach statements but if one supervisor is busy it will display the message which is not what I want.

**Code**

Method to distribute a job

```
bool finishLast = false;
bool successFirst = false;
while (successFirst != true)
{
    foreach (Supervisor sup in supervisors)
    {
        bool failure = false;
        while (failure != true)
        {
            foreach (Employee emp in employees)
            {
                if (emp.Busy == false && emp.Skills.HasFlag(_skillRequired) && successFirst == false)
                {
                    if (sup.SupervisorOccupied == false)
                    {
                        successFirst = true;
                        emp.EmployeeWorkload = _jobName;
                        emp.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
                        emp.Busy = true;
                        sup.EmployeeWorkload = "Supervising Employee: " + emp.EmployeeName + " to finish task: " + emp.EmployeeWorkload;
                        sup.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
                        sup.SupervisorOccupied = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (emp.Busy == true)
                {
                    failure = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (failure == true)
        {
            finishLast = true;
        }
    }
    if (finishLast == true)
    {
        successFirst = true;
    }
}
```

Of course if anyone can think of a simpler way of having this I will be open to ideas.

**EDIT 1**

This is not a multi-threaded system, yes `emp.Busy` and `sup.SupervisorOccupied` are technically the same thing, they are both in the `same class` so yes sup could inherit `emp.Busy`.

Comment: The usual thing that happens when I post indented code is that someone removes the indentation because they think it is hard to read, I proactively remove it before posting

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check if a supervisor is occupied before even looking at his employees? Does this value change depending on which employee you're looking at? Or does it change in the background, is this a multithreaded system?

Comment: Can you please update your question and add a real "GOAL"? You begin with describing what you are doing not what the result should be. I'm guessing you are allocating work on users but im not entirely clear how that should happen and what you starting point is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have tried both, for some reason the way I have it now works the best with my code, often the other way around is that the first 'batch' of employee/supervisor works but after that no more get allocated

Comment: It sounds like his goal is to find an employee that has the skills to accept a particular job, that is not busy, and is working under a supervisor that isn't occupied. Then, once find, allocate work to that employee, making him busy and his supervisor occupied.

Comment: Why the employee is "busy" and the supervisor "occupied" I don't know, is it the same thing?

Comment: Are supervisors and employees linked in some way? Or are they just linked when a workload is assigned to an employee, that employee needs a supervisor for that workload? How do you know which supervisor supervises which employee, other than that string for "EmployeeWorkload"?

Comment: After re-reading your code it sounds like you want to do the following: Find an available supervisor. Find an available employee with the skills for the job. Allocate the job to the employee and assign the supervisor to supervise that employee for that job. If this is correct you shouldn't have nested loops at all.

Comment: I suggest you remove all while loops and not required booleans because they are very confusing

Comment: I am having a lot of difficulty following the meaning of this short chunk of code as well, which is in itself just as much a problem as its apparent lack of correctness. A few things will help. First, stop doing `if (x != true)` etc. Equality produces a Boolean, but Booleans are *already* Boolean! If you mean `if (x == true)` or `while (x == true)` just say `if (x)` or `while (x)`. Instead of `if (x == false)` -- if it is true that x is false -- say `if (!x)` -- if the opposite of x is true.

Comment: Second, break this thing up into smaller methods, each of which does *something in the condition of the problem*. Like Lasse says, if part of the problem is to find an available supervisor then there should be a method `FindAvailableSupervisor` that returns either a supervisor or null if there is no such supervisor. Write that method, test the heck out of it, and *now you have a subsystem that you can rely on to solve a larger problem*.  Try to write the problem statement in terms of the business domain, and not how you intend to write the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
        bool assigned = false;
        foreach (Supervisor sup in supervisors)
        {
            if (!sup.SupervisorOccupied)
            {
                foreach (Employee emp in employees)
                {
                    if (!emp.Busy && emp.Skills.HasFlag(_skillRequired))
                    {
                        assigned = true;
                        emp.EmployeeWorkload = _jobName;
                        emp.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
                        emp.Busy = true;
                        sup.EmployeeWorkload = "Supervising Employee: " + emp.EmployeeName + " to finish task: " + emp.EmployeeWorkload;
                        sup.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
                        sup.SupervisorOccupied = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (assigned)
                break;
        }
```

if at the end "assigned == false", no employee is available (actually there's some code missing so it can't run, but theoretically it should do what you want!).

Comment: excellent, this seems to have worked, I knew I was over complicating it but at 4AM in the morning, one cannot be arsed to reformulate ideas, I will award you the answer in a short while

Comment: Good Danny happy to help. Have a look also at the other answers because you must have the opportunity to choose the implementation, and please "accept" the answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you should write that code:

```
var availableSupervisor = supervisors
    .FirstOrDefault(supervisor => !supervisor.SupervisorOccupied);
if (availableSupervisor == null)
    return;

var availableEmployee = employees
    .FirstOrDefault(employee => !employee.Busy && employee.Skills.HasFlag(_skillRequired));
if (availableEmployee == null)
    return;

availableEmployee.EmployeeWorkload = _jobName;
availableEmployee.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
availableEmployee.Busy = true;
availableSupervisor.EmployeeWorkload = "Supervising Employee: " + emp.EmployeeName + " to finish task: " + emp.EmployeeWorkload;
availableSupervisor.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
availableSupervisor.SupervisorOccupied = true;
```

Comment: Actually I don't like very much the use of Exceptions to control the program flow. Even if he said that this is not a multithreaded environment, I think it could easily happen that a piece of code like this that performs loops (maybe spending a while in there) is later moved into i.e. a timer: managing exceptions in this scenario would be definitely more complicated than i.e. updating an external "state" object that could carry i.e. also information about the progress of the operation (as well as the final result -the "assigned" boolean- obviously)

Comment: While your answer looks to be the most effective in terms of long run, I chose an answer that suited the context to which I was working, while I appreciate your comments and answer please do not think I have ignored your effort. Thanks.

Comment: @Lasse: This code would be a bit cleaner if you replaced  `.Where(supervisor => !supervisor.SupervisorOccupied).FirstOrDefault()` with `.FirstOrDefault(supervisor => !supervisor.SupervisorOccupied)`.  Obviously you could do the same to `availableEmployee`.

Comment: @LeonardoSpina: I agree with you that I dislike the use of exceptions, but I do think Lasse's approach is far superior to the OP's existing approach.  The exceptions could be replaced by loops.  Danny, I strongly encourage you to take Lasse's approach; your use of nested loops is harder to follow.  The nested loop approach is also less efficient, but that's easily fixed with an extra break statement under the employee loop (i.e., if you can't find a free employee for the first supervisor, don't bother checking for the next supervisor, either).

Comment: The exceptions are just one way to handle those cases, return statements, whatever, lots of other ways to handle those exit points.

Comment: @Brian Agreed, changed the answer, also changed the exceptions to return statements as these were just examples of where you would have to add logic to handle these situations.